# Ruby index assignment

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
items = ["place", "key", "holder"]
items[1,0] = ["bottle", "my"]
items # => ["place", "bottle", "my", "key", "holder"]
```

How did `"my"` come in third position?

Comment: Downvote it with an explanation pls.

Comment: Downvotes are possibly because this exact situation is explained in the docs for [`Array#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), which shows a lack of research effort. "Elements are inserted into the array at start if length is zero."

Comment: “I don’t understand this line” is a statement, not a question.

Comment: Thank you @SimpleLime, I should have checked there.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I was not sure how to frame it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref Array method of [`ary[start, length] = obj or other_ary or nil → obj or other_ary or nil`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.5/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)

```
items[1,0] = ["bottle", "my"]
Here, 1 is Index & Length is 0
```

As per the documentation 'Elements are inserted into the array at start if length & index are zero.'

For Ex:-

```
a = ['A']
a[0, 0] = [ 1, 2 ]          #=> array a will be [1, 2, "A"]
```

Similarly, when Index is non zero & Length is zero 'Elements are inserted into the array from given Index'

```
a = ['A']
a[1, 0] = [ 1, 2 ]          #=> array a will be ["A", 1, 2]
```

Comment: Your quotation is a bit off. The documentation says: _"Elements are inserted into the array at `start` if `length` is zero."_